# Insert a record into Cassandra table

Tags: cassandra

I created a table, university_by_person, as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE university_by_person (
    person_name frozen<name>,
    university_id uuid,
    university_name text,
    university_phone text,
    university_address frozen<address>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((person_name), university_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (university_id ASC)
    AND comment = 'Q1. Find universities(including university info) near a person';
```

And I also self-defined the TYPE name and address as the following:

```
CREATE TYPE name (
    first_name text,
    last_name text
)

CREATE TYPE address (
    street text,
    city text,
    state_or_province text,
    postal_code text,
    country text
)
```

However, now when I tried to insert a record into this table, and hit ENTER, the cmd prompt only returned '...'. It seems the cmd thought my command was not finished? But I did have a ';' at the end. How could I fix it here?

My insert command:

```
INSERT INTO  university_by_person
  (person_name, university_id, university_name, university_phone, university_address)
  VALUES (
    {first_name: 'Meryl', last_name: 'Streep'},
    e7ae5cf3-d358-4d99-b900-85902fda9bb0,
    'University of Toronto',
    '416-963-0086',
    {street: '27 King's College Cir', city: 'Toronto', state_or_province: 'Ontario', postal_code: 'M5S 1A1', country: 'Canada'}
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the value for `street` in the address is a string which contains a single quote (`'`) character:

```
street: '27 King's College Cir'
```

The `...` line in cqlsh indicates that it is expecting more input since the string got "terminated" prematurely.

To use an apostrophe within a string, you need to escape with another single quote so it looks like:

```
street: '27 King''s College Cir'
```

This is the full corrected CQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO university_by_person
  (person_name, university_id, university_name, university_phone, university_address)
  VALUES (
    {first_name: 'Meryl', last_name: 'Streep'},
    e7ae5cf3-d358-4d99-b900-85902fda9bb0,
    'University of Toronto',
    '416-963-0086',
    {street: '27 King''s College Cir', city: 'Toronto', state_or_province: 'Ontario', postal_code: 'M5S 1A1', country: 'Canada'}
  );
```

should execute as expected. The value of the column should also include the apostrophe:

```
cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT university_address FROM university_by_person
  WHERE person_name = {first_name: 'Meryl', last_name: 'Streep'};

 university_address
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {street: '27 King''s College Cir', city: 'Toronto', state_or_province: 'Ontario', postal_code: 'M5S 1A1', country: 'Canada'}
```

For more info and alernatives, see [Escaping characters](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/escape_char_r.html). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the comment! However, now when I fixed my code and reran it, I got this error:

**NoHostAvailable:**

Do you know why? Is it because how I defined my keyspace?

CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1};

Comment: Love the `stackoverfow` keyspace name.  Everyone needs one of those!

Comment: Ha ha @Aaron. :)